# unable to delete a content type from a webpart Sharepoint2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type

We have a custom webpart with a dropdown menu which contains some content types. We have changed some of the types but now I cannot change or delete the old content types. Its in use because before some documents have been created base don those contens. I cannot also delete those documents. Just want to delete or hide the content types. Is it possible?

Comment: Switch content type on all the documents that use the content type that you would like to remove. As soon as nothing uses the content type, you should be able to delete it.

Comment: Try from SharePoint Designer... Is there any error message getting logged in Event viewer??

Comment: @Christoffer its about 100 documents! not that easy and fast

Comment: If you are okay with losing the values for created, created by, modified and modified by, you should be able to open the library in the file explorer, copy all the contents to a temporary folder on your local desktop, delete the content type, and set a new default content type and then just drag and drop copy them back using file explorer once more.

Comment: @AnkitKumar is not possible also 'Could not save changes'. I can't even change the name

Answer (score 0):

As @Christoffer stated in comment, open document library with explorer which option is available in ribbon. Copy all documents in folder in local drive. Delete documents from document library. Delete content type and again copy all documents in document library with explorer.